# unknown validator even though it is in the Rails Guide on validators and callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am trying to validate that scores are greater than zero in my answer model when an answer is updated. Here is what i have so far.

```
validates :score, :greater_than => 0, :on => :update
```

However, i am getting this error:

```
Unknown validator: 'greater_than'
```

I found the greater_than validator [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#numericality). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Note that the 'only_integer' validation seems to have been intentionally-broken, too.  The rails syntax-fiddlers change their minds now and then, and rather than leave in things that work for backwards-compatibility, they choose to make your old, working code break, instead.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
validates :score, :numericality => {:greater_than => 0}, :on => :update
```